# matlab - vlfeat - vl_pegasos (svm) classification

Tags: matlab, svm, vlfeat

I am using the [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/) library in Matlab for some image analysis work. I want to use their Pegasos SVM implementation because of some of the kernels they have implemented, specifically, the Chi2 kernel.

However, I'm finding the documentation leaving me confused. Following [this tutorial](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/pegasos.html) I have a model `w` and a bias `b`, but how can I use that to classify my test data?

My starting data is like so (dimensions)..

```
size(train_data) = 
    200    210

size(train_labels) =
    1      210

size(test_data) =
    200    140

size(test_labels) =
    1      140
```

I can build a dataset with..

```
dataset = vl_maketrainingset(train_data, int8(train_labels))
```

giving me..

```
dataset = 
      data: [200x210 double]
    labels: [1x210 int8]
```

and then I can build the model..

```
[w b info] = vl_svmpegasos(dataset,0.01,'MaxIterations',5000);
```

`w` is my model ('w'eights?) is a vector size of size `200 x 1` with values ranging from 0 to 1.

I believe I need to multiply this vector by my `test_data` to get *scores* of some sort, but I'm not sure what the meaning of those scores would be.

Any direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at their [Caltech 101 example code](http://www.vlfeat.org/applications/apps.html)? It uses pegasos and gives a nice evaluation of the results.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                            Train SVM
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

lambda = 1 / (conf.svm.C *  length(selTrain)) ;
w = [] ;
for ci = 1:length(classes)
  perm = randperm(length(selTrain)) ;
  fprintf('Training model for class %s\n', classes{ci}) ;
  y = 2 * (imageClass(selTrain) == ci) - 1 ;
  data = vl_maketrainingset(psix(:,selTrain(perm)), int8(y(perm))) ;
  [w(:,ci) b(ci)] = vl_svmpegasos(data, lambda, ...
                                  'MaxIterations', 50/lambda, ...
                                  'BiasMultiplier', conf.svm.biasMultiplier) ;

  model.b = conf.svm.biasMultiplier * b ;
  model.w = w ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                Test SVM and evaluate
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% Estimate the class of the test images
scores = model.w' * psix + model.b' * ones(1,size(psix,2)) ;
[drop, imageEstClass] = max(scores, [], 1) ;

% Compute the confusion matrix
idx = sub2ind([length(classes), length(classes)], ...
              imageClass(selTest), imageEstClass(selTest)) ;
confus = zeros(length(classes)) ;
confus = vl_binsum(confus, ones(size(idx)), idx) ;
```